# PowerShell Script Works Locally But Not Remotely

Tags: powershell

I have developed a PowerShell that installs an MSI and this works fine when you run it locally, but if I call it remotely from another server all that happens is that my command simply returns without error message or anything else.

Now, I have set on both servers the execution policy to be unrestricted, and the command I am running from the remote server is as far as I am concerned simple:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName MyComputer.MyDomain -ScriptBlock {
    & "C:\InstallSoftware\install.ps1"
}
```

Now, I have run another command using the `Invoke-command` `Get-Culture` and this returned the server name and its culture.

So, I am at a loss why this is failing to run!

Comment: Is the script path (`C:\InstallSoftware\install.ps1`) valid on the remote system?  Also, what does this script do?  For example, does it install the MSI from a further server?  This might lead to authentication issues.

Comment: The path on the remote server is valid and there is no pulling the executable from another server. It is just one server calling another

Comment: You configured the ps1 extension on your systems to automatically execute powershell files? that is not the default or particularly good practice. Or is it a case of you need to `powershell.exe -File "C:\InstallSoftware\install.ps1"`

Comment: I am guessing you are talking about the execution policy? So it is poweshell calling poweshell

Comment: The funny thing is that I have another powershell script that uninstall the software and that works. All that the install script is doing is calling msiexec.exe

Comment: "Doesn't work" is not a valid problem description. How *exactly* does it "not work"? Are you getting an error? Is the script not invoked? How did you verify? Does something in the script fail? How? What is the content of the script?

Comment: If you read my description, I said no error message is given. Further, I also said that the script works locally when typing . /install.ps1

Comment: Does running it using  `-Filepath`  over `-Scriptblock` work? i.e. `Invoke-Command -ComputerName MyComputer.MyDomain -Filepath "C:\InstallSoftware\install.ps1"`  This way you are pulling the script from the local PC rather than from the remote PC

Comment: No that wouldn't because it would point the filepath to the machine you are on

Comment: @Andy5 That is not how `Invoke-Command -FilePath` works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my answer here https://powershellexplained.com/2017-04-22-Powershell-installing-remote-software/?utm_source=blog&utm_medium=blog&utm_content=installingmsifiles

The most important thing to understand here is the -Wait parameter to ensure that the remote server has completed its task. Not setting this forces the task to finish

Comment: Meaning it was something *inside* the script that you were running, but didn't show to us, thus making the question unanswerable for anyone without access to your computer. That is *precisely* why the guidelines are asking you to provide a [mcve], and also what the questions in my comment (that you decided to brush over) were meant to help unravel. So maybe the next time someone asks you for clarification, you could pause for a minute and actually answer those questions?

Comment: Sure. Except it wasn't. Like I already pointed out, the issue is not with the code you posted, but with the content of the script you're running (which apparently is running something asynchronously that doesn't complete when `Invoke-Command` returns without waiting for it). I explicitly asked for the code of the script you were running, which you chose to ignore.